# Searching for tweets by using multiple keywords connected with OR condition doesn't work as expected in Twitter?

Tags: twitter

On Twiiter.com (or when using Twitter REST API), I can search for tweets by keywords "Azure SQL Data Warehouse" (wrapped by double quotes) and it works. I can also search for tweets by keyword AzureSQLDW and it works too. But if I search for tweets by using the below search syntax, the search result contains less tweets.

"Azure SQL Data Warehouse" OR AzureSQLDW

My assumption is, the search results should contain both tweets for keywords "Azure SQL Data Warehouse" and tweets for keyword AzureSQLDW. But many tweets for keyword AzureSQLDW are missing.

Eventually I will use Twitter REST API. And I'd like less number of API calls. So I'd prefer putting all keywords in a single API call. But looks like the search result contains less than I need. Anyone knows if it's by design or I'm using wrong search syntax? Thanks!

Comment: can you show your code for the api call?

Comment: based on the dev.twitter.com docs the query should be valid: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search however there might be some other ranking system be at play behind the scenes that is omitting expected results. This seems to happen with the facebook.com api as well